# Why my page is too wide when using RTL?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, right-to-left

This is a WordPress issue and I'm asking this question here because I believe it is a CSS problem.

I'm using Wordpress and a theme named ShootinStar but I have to do my website in an RTL language. The theme supports RTL though.

Everything is perfect when the language of WordPress is English but once I change it to Farsi, then the width of my theme increases by maybe 4 times.

The website is visible and clear but you can actually swipe to left and see the rest of the background in a wide area.

Pages are fine, no problems with that. But the 'Post page' where I do my blogging which is my main page, is facing this issue. I tried assigning it to a page, but then that page will have the same problem.

I tried disabling plug-ins and changing themes, but nothing happened. I'm guessing that it is a CSS problem, but where is it exactly? I attached  screenshots and highlighted the parts with red arrows.

This is after using element inspector:

What shall I do?!

Comment: any link of this site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this CSS code to remove the unwanted space in the x-axis direction.

```
#container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Anyway, do you think I should do it in a child theme or not?

Comment: Yes, always the child theme.

Comment: The problem is solved for PC but when using a smart phone ( although the theme is responsive ) the problem is still there. The exact same codes!

Comment: Replace the body with #wrapper or #container. The latter will work most of the time.

Comment: I updated the question with a new image. The highlighted #wrapper is used to be body and I replaced it with #wrapper. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I just checked in my smartphone after finding the same issue. The excess space is not shown. Clear cache in mobile?

Comment: I checked it with device mode in element inspection and it shows up fine, but not on my phone! That might be from the cache.

Comment: and yessss, it was from the cache!
Thanks man, I really appreciate all your efforts.